# Unicode not showing correctly in IOS

Tags: text, unicode, dart, flutter

i am using unicode to show superscript in flutter, but it showing in different size, and the problem is only with IOS, working fine in android.

```
 Text("ˢᵍ"),
 Text("ᴾᴸ"),
 Text("\u02e2\u1d4d"),
 Text("\u1d3e\u1d38"),
```

```
Flutter doctor result 

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

RESULT SCREEN
[image]

Comment: I'd file an issue (if there is none already)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer did you file issue, can i track.

Comment: No, I meant I would file an issue if I were you.